# Get non repeating subpath using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to get all unique paths to Child without the subpaths being part of the collection

Assuming my graph looks like

```
 (A :GrandParent)-[RELATED_TO]->(B :Parent)-[RELATED_TO]->(C :Child)
 (X :GrandParent)-[RELATED_TO]->(Y :Child)
 (L :Child)
```

The query

```
MATCH path=(n)-[RELATED_TO*0..3]->(:Child)
WHERE n:GrandParent OR n:Parent
RETURN nodes(path)
```

Would return

```
A->B->C
B->C
C
X->Y
Y
```

Is there a way to make sure

- `B->C` is not returned since it is already a part of the `A->B->C` path
- `C` is not returned since its already covered in `A->B->C` path
- `L` is returned since its not already covered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the data provided you can rephrase the question to make it easier - you seem to only want paths that start with a 'root' node, a node that has no inbound `RELATED_TO` relationships. In your dataset that would yield A, X and L which are then also the traversals we're after.

Given some sample data:

```
MERGE (A: GrandParent { name: 'A' })
MERGE (B: Parent { name: 'B' })
MERGE (C: Child { name: 'C' })
MERGE (X: Grandparent { name: 'X' })
MERGE (Y: Child { name: 'Y' })
MERGE (L: Child { name: 'L' })
MERGE (A)-[:RELATED_TO]->(B)
MERGE (B)-[:RELATED_TO]->(C)
MERGE (X)-[:RELATED_TO]->(Y)
```

The following query eliminates paths that start with a node that has an incoming `RELATED_TO` relationship:

```
MATCH path=(p)-[RELATED_TO*0..]->(:Child)
WHERE NOT (()-[:RELATED_TO]->(p))
RETURN nodes(path)
```

Yielding the result you described:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"nodes(path)"                           │
╞════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"},{"name":"C"}]│
├────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"X"},{"name":"Y"}]             │
├────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"L"}]                          │
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Though it's unclear what you'd expect to happen if a node had more than one child.

Comment: Hey Pablissimo, thanks fr the response.
This indeed gets the correct graph and I do agree that i should have formulated the question a bit better
I was in a rush and forgot one important aspect of in the question and that was that even the `root` node might have other nodes related to it with the same `[:RELATED_TO]` relation
Would there be a way to handle that aswell?